# how to check if user is logged in by his session in route and then call controller method in laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I want to check user session in routes file, so that if session is set user can visit dashboard otherwise redirect to login page.

I have used following code for this but it's not working. It's not giving any error and not redirecting him to login page. anyhow if I write same code in controller functioin, it works fine.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard/index', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@index'], function() {
    $value = $request->session()->get('name', 'not_loggin');
    if ($value == 'not_loggin') {
        return redirect('/user/login');
    }
    });
});
```

it also didn't worked if I write it in constructor.

Comment: Why not just use the auth middleware?

Comment: Route::get('dashboard/index', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);

Comment: thanks @MateiMihai it worked, I've just started laravel so having problem in deciding what to use. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `auth` middleware:

```
Route::get('dashboard/index', [
   'middleware' => 'auth',
   'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
]);
```